# OpsWorks run hook on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, slack-api

I'm using OpsWorks to do production deployments and I want to have a notification hook (specifically, a Slack webhook) that runs after a deployment succeeds successfully.

I could make a recipe to do this, but recipes run on every instance, which (I think) would carry out N hooks (where N is the number of instances). I really only want a hook to run when *all* instances are finished deploying.

Is there any way to run code when an app has finished deploying to all OpsWorks instances?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! (Well sorta kinda...) There're the [Chef Deployment Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html).

In your case, since you what to run it just once, you will have to find a way to "choose" one server and run your code on the `after_restart` or in the hooks workout some other way of ensuring that's it is the "last one" deployed.

Below is an example that will always tell you if the current instance it is the "leader" one, so to choose just one instance to run something:

```
available_instances = new_resource.node[:opsworks][:layers]['php-app'][:instances]
available_instances = available_instances.select { |name, instance|
  ['requested', 'booting', 'running_setup', 'online'].include?(instance[:status])
}
leader_name = available_instances.keys.sort.first
leader = new_resource.node[:opsworks][:layers]['php-app'][:instances][leader_name]

if leader && new_resource.node[:opsworks][:instance]
  is_leader = leader[:aws_instance_id] == new_resource.node[:opsworks][:instance][:aws_instance_id]
else
  is_leader = true
end
```